# Simplenews Scheduler Sending Newsletter Twice a Week

Tags: emails, cron

I'm having trouble configuring how to send a simplenews newsletter to subscribed users twice a week.  I'm using Simplenews scheduler but just don't know how to configure it.  I want to send a newsletter of all my updated content to my users on Sunday and Thursday.

I've got everything else working, just don't know how to configure it to send on Sunday and Thursday.  In Simplenews Scheduler, we can schedule it to start sending on a specific day like Sunday and set the Sending interval to 'Day', then, set Interval Frequency to 4.  But I am certain that after the first two times, the days will shift and the third time it will send on Monday and fourth time on Friday and just keep shifting a day each time.

So, hope you guys have some ideas on how to configure it correctly.

Comment: Since, I've still got no answers, I'm thinking of using Rules to do this.  Perhaps run Cron for Rules every hour and then, add a Rule that would trigger on Cron, and then, the condition would be to check if it is Thursday or Sunday, if so, the action would be to send the newsletter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way of solving it without Rules, you can use Simplenews Scheduler.

Simply create two different Simplenews nodes of the same Simplenews category. You can use the same views token (or whatever you use to fill in the content of the newsletter) in both nodes.

Then set one node to send on Sunday weekly, and the other on Thursday weekly.

This can be done because Scheduler is set per node, not per category, and also subscribers are subscribed to Categories, not nodes, so each time all of the subscribers will receive the news, no matter if Sunday or Thursday nodes happen to be sent.